# rotate() in canvas has no effect

Tags: android, android-animation, android-canvas

When I use the rotate method with my canvas object, the canvas object doesn't rotate. Why is this happening? Here is my code

```
package com.example.hello;

    import android.app.Activity; import android.content.Context; import android.graphics.Canvas; import android.graphics.Color; import android.graphics.Paint; import android.os.Bundle; import android.view.View; import android.widget.LinearLayout;

    public class CanvasDrawExample extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.example);
    LinearLayout rl=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.rl);
     rl.addView(new CircleView(this));
    }
public class CircleView extends View
{

    public CircleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub


    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        Paint p=new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        p.setStrokeWidth(100);
        p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        p.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        canvas.drawRect(200, 100, 200, 100, p);
        canvas.save();  
        canvas.rotate((float)145);

        canvas.restore();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: are you able to draw blue color Rect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You save your canvas, rotate it and then restore it without doing any drawing on it. If you are trying to rotate the Rectangle 145º to the right, do the following:

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        canvas.save();  
        canvas.rotate((float)-145,canvas.getWidth()/2,canvas.getHeight()/2);

        Paint p=new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        p.setStrokeWidth(100);
        p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        p.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        canvas.drawRect(200, 100, 200, 100, p);


        canvas.restore();
    }
```

Also, it is not recommended to instantiate and define a Paint inside onDraw(). You should declare and define it in the constructor and then, reuse it.

Comment: I updated the code, you probably need to specify the pivot point

Comment: Still the same thing rectangle doesn't appear.

Comment: canvas.drawRect(200, 100, 200, 100, p);
The left and right sides of your Rectangle are the same. So  are the top and bottom sides

Comment: how does that affect the rotation>?

Comment: It does not affect the rotation but your Rectangle. If you remove the rotation, does it show?

Comment: What I meant was can you please explain me about the rotation?

Comment: In order to rotate objects on your canvas, you must rotate the canvas itself and not the object(drawing). Think of the Canvas as a sheet of paper. If you want to draw a rectangle 45º to the right, what you are probably going to do is rotate the paper 45º to the left, draw your rectangle and then, put the paper back to it's initial position.
This is what you do with the save(), rotate() and restore() methods.

Comment: but the problem seems to be with the dimensions when I changed them to a different value it worked. But how should I exactly put the dimensions?

Comment: Read the doc: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html
You should think of the parameters like this: top left X, top left Y, bottom right X, bottom right Y

Comment: Yes I understand that but why don't I see a rectangle when I draw it using canvas.drawRect(10,30,10,30,p); ?

Comment: Because the Rectangle does not have any dimension: 0px width and 0px height (the top left and bottom right corners are the same point)

Comment: So this means that the rectangle is plotted using these four locations. Got it now thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In order this to work you need to comment the canvas.restore();